# I need to add a second hard drive to the FreeBSD system that hosts my Apache server.

Tags: apache, freebsd

I need to add a second hard drive into the FreeBSD system that hosts my Apache server.  The drive is installed and accessible by the FreeBSD system.

I have been searching for a way to access that data on the new drive using the Apache web server, and can't find any specifics on how to allow the Apache to access the data on the second drive.

Any suggestions about where to look?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your httpd.conf already has a <Directory> section for the document root. Duplicate it for the mountpoint of your additional drive, and add an Alias/AliasMatch to expose that mountpoint under whatever URL you want.